# Solving $\tan(x) + x = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\tan(x) + x = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

I want to find the solution where

$$0 < x < 1$$

EDIT: Why there are no closed form solution?
Maybe sin(...) or cos(...) or tan(...)

For example, the equation
$$64x^6 -112x^4 + 56x^2 - 7 = 0$$

have a simple solution

$x = sin\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$

Comment: There are no closed form solution.  Use a numerical method.

Comment: I found it. It is $0.7104627377755168567474282675020891\ldots$

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/am3msb4esv

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7BTan%5Bx%5D%2Bx%3DPi%2F2%2C0%3Cx%3C1%7D%2Cx%5D

Comment: Why there are no closed form solution? Maybe sin(a) or cos(b) or tan(c)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic inspection, you know the the root is close to $\frac \pi 4$.

To have an approximation, use Taylor series around this value to get
$$\tan(x)+x-\frac \pi 2=\left(1-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+3 \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^2\right)$$ and a first *estimate* is
$$x=\frac{\pi -1}{3}\sim 0.713864$$ which is not so bad (at this point, the expression is $\sim 0.00934$.

Now, use a numerical method or approximation. For the fun of it, I give you one
$$x\sim\frac{-2012160+1477632 \pi +256128 \pi ^2+34752 \pi ^3+3048 \pi ^4+192 \pi
   ^5}{5004288+863232 \pi +119808 \pi ^2+9792 \pi ^3+768 \pi ^4}$$ which is $0.710462753$ (very close to @Gary's accurate result).

**Edit**

Using an high order series expansion and continuing with series reversion, we end with
$$x \sim \frac \pi 4+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\, t^n \quad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac {\pi -4}{12}$$ and the first $a_n$ are
$$\left\{1,-\frac{2}{3},0,\frac{10}{27},-\frac{56}{405},-\frac{292}{1215},\frac{272}{
   1701},\frac{382}{1701},-\frac{7288}{32805},-\frac{769396}{3444525}\right\}$$ Using it, then
$$x \sim \color{blue}{0.7104627377755}93$$